# Weak-* sequential compactness and separability

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $X^*$, equipped with the weak-* topology.  Alaoglu's theorem says that $B$ is compact.  If $X$ is separable, then $B$ is metrizable, and in particular it is sequentially compact.

> What about the converse?  If $B$ is sequentially compact, must $X$ be separable?

This question was inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168635/weak-convergence-of-regular-measures).

Comment: Wouldn't $B$ be weak* sequentially compact in any reflexive space by Eberlein's theorem?

Comment: @DavidMitra: You are quite right.  I had forgotten about Eberlein.  Want to post this as an answer?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234722/when-is-the-dual-ball-of-l-1-mu-weak-sequentially-compact

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Any reflexive Banach space has a weakly compact unit ball; so, by the [Eberlein-Šmulian Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem), any reflexive Banach space has a weak* sequentially compact unit ball.

Also, and more generally, it follows from Rosenthal's $\ell_1$ Theorem (a Banach space $X$ does not contain $\ell_1$ isomorphically if and only if every every bounded sequence in $X$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence) that if $X^*$ does not contain $\ell_1$ isomorphically, then the unit ball of $X^*$ is weak* sequentially compact.

Answer (score 5):

For an explicit counterexample: let $H$ be a non-separable Hilbert space, and suppose we have a sequence of vectors $x_n$ in the unit ball of $H$.  Let $H_0$ be the closed linear span of the $x_n$, so that $H_0$ is a separable Hilbert space.  Then the $x_n$ have a subsequence converging weakly in $H_0$.  But because of the orthogonal decomposition $H = H_0 \oplus H_0^\perp$, it is easy to see that this subsequence also converges weakly in $H$.

Answer (score 3):

To characterize Banach spaces for which the dual ball is weak* sequentially compact is an **open question**! See Chapter XIII of Diestel, *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces* for a discussion on that topic.