# When is the dual ball of $L_1(\mu)$ weak*-sequentially compact?

Tags: banach-spaces, compactness

Where could I find a direct proof showing that the dual ball of $L_1(\mu)$ is weak*-sequentially compact?

Since $(L_1(\mu))^*=L_\infty(\mu)$, I mean the unit ball $B_{L_\infty(\mu)}$ of $L_\infty(\mu)$ with the topology $\sigma(L_\infty(\mu),L_1(\mu))$.

(Eberlein-Smulian yields that $B_{L^\infty}$ is $\omega$-sequentially compact.)

Comment: $L^1$ as in $L^1(\Omega,\mu)$? What properties is the measure $\mu$ assumed to have?

Comment: Ok. $\mu$ is a probability.

Comment: That implies $L^1$ is separable, iirc. If $X$ is separable, then the closed unit ball of $X^\ast$ is metrisable in the weak$^\ast$-topology, and compact metric spaces are sequentially compact.

Comment: Thank you. Now I only have to figure out why L^1 is separable ...

Comment: ... but I'm afraid that L^1 is not always separable! Even when $\mu$ is a probability

Comment: Then it seems I didn't recall correctly. Have you an example of a finite measure where $L^1$ isn't separable?

Comment: well, to be honest I don't have any counterexample off the top of my head. I need to search more. But I always find extraconditions in every theorem. For instance, if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and the $\sigma$-algebra is countably generated, then $L^p$ ($1\leq p <\infty$) is separable. This made me think that we cannot guarantee $L^1$ to be sepable ...

Comment: Could be that finiteness of the measure is not sufficient for $L^1$ to be separable. In that case, I have at the moment no idea for a direct proof of sequential compactness.

Comment: Daniel, $L_1(\{0,1\}^{\omega_1})$ is non-separable even though the Haar measure on $\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$ is finite.

Comment: Zap, would you please revisit my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**zap**, the unit ball of $L_\infty(\mu)$ is not weakly compact (hence not weakly sequentially compact either) because $L_\infty(\mu)$ is not reflexive apart from the trivial cases.

The result you are interested in follows from two facts.

**Theorem** (Amir–Lindenstrauss). Let $X$ be a [weakly compactly generated Banach space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/WCG_space). Then weak*-compact subsets of $X^*$ are weak*-sequentially compact.

> D. Amir and J. Lindenstrauss, [The structure of weakly compact
>   sets in Banach spaces](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970554?uid=3738032&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106103059261), *Ann. Math.* **88** (1968), 35–46.

**Fact**. Let $\mu$ be a finite measure. Then $L_1(\mu)$ is weakly compactly generated. Indeed, the inclusion map from the reflexive space $L_2(\mu)$ to $L_1(\mu)$ has dense range (and is injective of course).

**Observation**. We can extend our conclusion to $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$. Indeed, the Radon–Nikodym theorem yields an isometry from $L_1(\mu)$ to some $L_1(\nu)$ where $\nu$ is a finite measure.

Comment: Now, if I am not wrong, I see that it is not necessary the Amir-Lindenstrauss Theorem. Indeed, Fact I: Due to the Eberlein-Smulian theorem and since $L_2^*=L_2$, we have that the dual unit ball of $L^2$ is weak*-sequentially compact. Fact II: It is not difficult to show that the class of  Banach spaces having weak-∗ sequentially
compact dual ball is closed under the operation of taking dense continuous
linear images. Fact II: It suffices to consider the injection $L_2\rightarrow L_1$, which has dense range.