# A coarser topology of the topology with 'compact set equals sequentially compact set'

Tags: general-topology, compactness, weak-convergence

I study about weak and weak* topology in functional analysis.

By Eberlein-Smulian, every weakly compact set is weakly sequentially compact. How about weak* topology? I learned that $(B_{X^*},\omega^*)$($\omega^*$ means weak* topology.) is metrizable when $X$ is separable, so it is clearly true for $(B_{X^*},\omega^*)$, but I don't know the result for $(X^*,\omega^*)$.

On the other hand, does this hold about general topology? i.e., if $(X,\tau_1)$ is a topological space that $\{K\subset X:K$ is compact$\}$=$\{K\subset X:K$ is sequentially compact$\}$ and $(X,\tau_2)$ is a coarser topology than $\tau_1$, does the same hold for $(X,\tau_2)$? I think it is false but cannot find examples.

Comment: The weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$ is metrizable if $X$ is separable, but not in general.

Comment: I confused something about weak* topology. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.  The last statement of my comment was incorrect.  I confused the content of the Banach-Alouglu theorem to be about the weak topology. Nevertheless, it is still relevant.

Comment: Ok! Have a good day

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168718/weak-sequential-compactness-and-separability) is a related post. One can show that  for $X=\ell_1(\Bbb R)$, $B_{X^*}$ is not weak* sequentially compact.

Comment: Thanks you! So the second question is also false.

Answer (score 1):

The weak* topology of $X^*$ is never sequential, unless $X$ is finite-dimensional. To see this , you may modify [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029853/is-the-weak-topology-sequential-on-some-infinite-dimensional-banach-space/2030014#2030014).

Comment: That post asks whether or not every weakly sequentially closed set is weakly closed.  This post asks whether or not weak$^*$ sequential compactness is equivalent to weak$^*$ compactness, which is the case when $X$ reflexive.

Comment: How can I relate sequentially closed and sequentially compact? Are they equivalent?

Comment: @Aweygan, there are two questions: the first one is about metrasibility/sequentiality of $X^*$ in the weak*-topology.